# Why do we use log probability in deep learning?

Tags: math, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I got curious while reading the paper 'Sequence to Sequence Learning with Neural Networks'.
In fact, not only this paper but also many other papers use log probabilities, is there a reason for that?
Please check the attached photo.

[image]

Comment: The product of *N* probabilities tends to zero as *N* gets large. This can mean floating point underflow and loss of precision. The log of the product is equal to the sum of the logs and the individual logs should be reasonably sized negative numbers and their sum should retain full precision

Answer (score 3):

Two reasons -

1. **Theoretical** - Probabilities of two independent events A and B co-occurring together is given by P(A).P(B). This easily gets mapped to a sum if we use log, i.e. log(P(A)) + log(P(B)). It is thus easier to address the neuron firing 'events' as a linear function.
2. **Practical** - The probability values are in [0, 1]. Hence multiplying two or more such small numbers could easily lead to an underflow in a floating point precision arithmetic (e.g. consider multiplying 0.0001*0.00001). A practical solution is to use the logs to get rid of the underflow.

Answer (score 1):

For any given problem we need to optimise the likelihood of parameters. But optimising the product require all data at once and requires huge computation.

We know that a sum is a lot easier to optimise as the derivative of a sum is the sum of derivatives. So, taking log convert it to sum and makes computation faster.

Refer [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174481/why-to-optimize-max-log-probability-instead-of-probability)