# Sampling from a set according to unnormalized log-probabilities in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a 1-D `np.ndarray` filled with unnormalized log-probabilities that define a categorical distribution. I would like to sample an integer index from this distribution. Since many of the probabilities are small, normalizing and exponentiating the log-probabilities introduces significant numerical error, therefore I cannot use [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). Effectively, I am looking for a NumPy equivalent to TensorFlow's [`tf.random.categorical`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/categorical), which works on unnormalized log-probabilities.

If there is not a function in NumPy that achieves this directly, what is an efficient manner to implement such sampling?

Comment: *"Since many of the probabilities are small, normalizing and exponentiating the log-probabilities introduces significant numerical error, "*  Do you have an example of a set of log-probabilities that demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Not that I can conveniently post. It's [well known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63334122/why-do-we-use-log-probability-in-deep-learning) that using log-probabilities prevents underflow from arising.

The sampling is done as part of an importance sampling algorithm I am implementing. Therefore, many of the probabilities involved are small (order 1e-8). I have had issues in the past where I end up getting NaNs when converting from unnormalized log-probabilities to normalized probabilities.

Comment: Can you at least give some typical values for how many log-probabilities you have, and what a typical range is for the values of the log-probabilities?  1e-8 doesn't seem small enough to cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there are [many ways to choose an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027757/data-structure-for-loaded-dice/63166311#63166311) with a custom distribution, but most of them take weights that are *proportional* to the given probabilities. If the weights are log probabilities instead, then a slightly different approach is needed. Perhaps the simplest algorithm for this is rejection sampling, described below and implemented in Python. In the following algorithm, the maximum log-probability is `max`, and there are `k` integers to choose from.

1. Choose a uniform random integer `i` in [0, `k`).
2. Get the log-weight corresponding to `i`, then generate an exponential(1) random number, call it `ex`.
3. If `max` minus `ex` is less than the log-weight, return `i`. Otherwise, go to step 1.

The time complexity for rejection sampling is constant on average, especially if `max` is set to equal the true maximum weight. On the other hand, the expected number of iterations per sample depends greatly on the shape of the distribution. See also [Keith Schwarz's discussion](https://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/) on the "Fair Die/Biased Coin Loaded Die" algorithm.

Now, Python code for this algorithm follows.

```
import random
import math

def categ(c):
 # Do a weighted choice of an item with the
 # given log-probabilities.
 cm=max(c) # Find max log probability
 while True:
      # Choose an item at random
      x=random.randint(0,len(c)-1)
      # Choose it with probability proportional
      # to exp(c[x])
      y=cm-random.expovariate(1)
      # Alternatively: y=math.log(random.random())+cm
      if y<c[x]:
          return x
```

The code above generates one variate at a time and uses only Python's base modules, rather than NumPy. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64881410/815724) shows how rejection sampling can be implemented in NumPy by blocks of random variates at a time (demonstrated on a different random sampling task, though).

---

The so-called "[Gumbel max trick](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.01515)", used above all in machine learning, can be used to sample from a distribution with unnormalized log probabilities. This involves—

1. ("Gumbel") adding a separate *Gumbel* random variate to each log probability, namely −ln(−ln(*U*)) where *U* is a random variate greater than 0 and less than 1, then
2. ("max") choosing the item corresponding to the highest log probability.

However, the time complexity for this algorithm is linear in the number of items.

The following code illustrates the Gumbel max trick:

```
import random
import math

def categ(c):
 # Do a weighted choice of an item with the
 # given log-probabilities, using the Gumbel max trick
 return max([[c[i]-math.log(-math.log(random.random())),i] \
      for i in range(len(c))])[1]
 # Or:
 # return max([[c[i]-math.log(random.expovariate(1)),i] \
 #   for i in range(len(c))])[1]
```